# How to post ipython notebook thread into Wordpress blog?

Tags: wordpress, blogs, jupyter-notebook

I know nbconvert and I am able to convert notebook file into html but I cannot find a way to embed this html file into wordpress. Is there anyone who tried and succeed?

Comment: As far as I can tell, no.

http://jeffskinnerbox.wordpress.com/2013/09/02/im-moving-so-i-can-blog-with-ipython-notebook/

Comment: Wordpress.com or self hosted?

Answer (score 0):

We can solve this issue using [Simple Mathjax Plugi](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-mathjax/)n. For that please follow the below steps:

1. Install and Activate the plugin.
2. Disable WordPress HTML code parsing(this is for displaying the images in the HTML output).
3. Copy and paste the HTML output of nbconvert (content inside the `<body>` tag) in the Text tab.